I cannot install numpy: pip tries to build numpy and fails
(myvenv) PS E:\Python> pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.10.0.84.tar.gz (95.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [66 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment   
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment    
      Collecting cmake>=3.1
        Using cached cmake-3.30.3.tar.gz (31 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting numpy>=2.0.0
        Downloading numpy-2.0.2.tar.gz (18.9 MB)
           ---------------------------------------- 18.9/18.9 MB 3.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [23 lines of output]
        + E:\Python\myvenv\bin\python.exe C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nzei4sh_\numpy_a368f9e2aa274993be96d795ef79ddd4\vendored-mes
on\meson\meson.py setup C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nzei4sh_\numpy_a368f9e2aa274993be96d795ef79ddd4 C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\T
emp\pip-install-nzei4sh_\numpy_a368f9e2aa274993be96d795ef79ddd4\.mesonpy-cclotgs2 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nzei4sh_\numpy_a368f9e2aa274993be96d795ef79ddd4\.mesonpy-cclotgs2\meson-python-native-file.ini     
        The Meson build system
        Version: 1.4.99
        Source dir: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nzei4sh_\numpy_a368f9e2aa274993be96d795ef79ddd4
        Build dir: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nzei4sh_\numpy_a368f9e2aa274993be96d795ef79ddd4\.mesonpy-cclotgs2
        Build type: native build
        Project name: NumPy
        Project version: 2.0.2
        C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 12.1.0 "cc (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0")
        C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.38
        C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 12.1.0 "c++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0")
        C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.38
        Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 3.0.11)
        Host machine cpu family: x86_64
        Host machine cpu: x86_64
        Program python found: YES (E:\Python\myvenv\bin\python.exe)
        Found pkg-config: YES (C:\mingw64\bin\pkg-config.EXE) 1.8.0
        Could not find Python3 library 'E:\\Python\\myvenv\\lib\\libpython3.9.dll.a'
        Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried pkgconfig, pkgconfig and sysconfig)

        ..\meson.build:41:12: ERROR: Python dependency not found

        A full log can be found at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nzei4sh_\numpy_a368f9e2aa274993be96d795ef79ddd4\.mesonpy-cclotgs2\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      Encountered error while generating package metadata.

      See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I set cmake and I installed many times, it still does not run.

Try to recreate environment, and it seems there is issue with python version.

Upgrade pip, setuptools, and wheel: Old versions of these tools can create problems. From the error message logs it also looks like there maybe a library is missing somewhere. I request you try a small numpy example code seperately and see if it runs. Also try an OpenCV project like face detection. Here is a simple OpenCV project. https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/This_Robot_Loves_Money_cf706346.html

"I cannot import" -- that's rather misleading, you haven't even managed to install the library. | Also, why is it trying to use MinGW for the build? What exact build of Python is in E:\Python\myvenv\ -- standard Windows one, or MSYS-based one?

this isn't new (and not related to OpenCV either). recently there have been issues installing numpy. there have been several questions, with answers, on this. if you don't look those up, someone else might do it for you. I'm not inclined to, at the moment.

@DanMašek is right on track. Building numpy from source with native windows build tools is already quite challenging, but using msys, it just gets more complicated, especially for a beginner. Since you want opencv, why not use a pre built package?
